# name 'win' is not defined - pygame

Tags: text, pygame

I'm trying to implement some text into my game. I've followed a tutorial that has led me to this

```py
pygame.font.init()
gamefont = pygame.font.SysFont('Bahnschrift', 16)
text = gamefont.render("Round: ", 1, (0,0,0))
win.blit(text, (390, 10))
```

However, when I run my code, it says that the name 'win' is not defined. I was wondering if anyone knew how to fix this?

Comment: Where is `win` set up in your code?

Comment: I haven't set up `win` anywhere, I'm assuming this is where I'm going wrong? @mkusz

Comment: Yes, you need to set up a display first before you blit anything on it. Is there more to your code than this?

Answer (score 0):

`win` is the `pygame.Surface` object which is associated to the window.
Somewhere you have t o initialize pygame (`pygame.init()`) and to create the window Surface (`pygame.display.set_mode`):

Minimal applicaiton:

```py
import pygame

# initializations
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# create font ad render text
pygame.font.init()
gamefont = pygame.font.SysFont('Bahnschrift', 16)
text = gamefont.render("Round: ", 1, (0,0,0))

# main application loop
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear the display
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))

    # draw the text   
    win.blit(text, (390, 10))

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thanks @Rabbid76 , I tried putting your code into my game and thankfully I did get the text I wanted! However it did delete the rest of my game so that i was just left with a white screen that said "Round: ". So I'm thinking I need to put the parts of the code in different places?